# how to bind mvvm visible and text properties to child item kendo ui menu

Tags: mvvm, menu, kendo-ui

I'm trying to bind visible property and text to kendo ui menu. I use MVVM framework. When I change property in viewModel child menu item not visible not work. This is html code from my [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FreeClimb/a13Ldf58/19/):

```
<ul id="menu" data-role="menu">
    <li>
        <span class="fa fa-globe"></span>
        Map
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/home/index"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Index</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/home/about"><span class="fa fa-info"></span>Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li data-bind="visible: isLogout">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: logIn">
            <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>
            Log in
        </a>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: isLogin">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: userName"></span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-key"></span>Change password</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-tags"></span>Refresh token</a></li>
            <li class="k-separator"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span>Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and js:

```
var viewModel = kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    isLogin: false,
    isLogout: true,
    userName: "",
    logIn: function(e) {
        //var text = $(e.item).children(".k-link").text();
        this.userName = "Jane Smith"; //John Smith
        this.isLogin = true;
        this.isLogout = false;
    }
});
kendo.bind($("#menu"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the value to a property call the observable method `set` like this:

`var _this = this;
this.set("userName", "Jane Smith");
this.set("isLogin", true);`

Assigning to the property directly doesn't allow the change events to propagate through the bindings.

Also, instead of binding the visibility of the two elements to two properties, as they're related to each other you can use a combination of the `visible` and `invisible` binding to the same property.

`<li data-bind="visible: isLogin"></li>
<li data-bind="invisible: isLogin"></li>`

Comment: thanks for your fix and advice.  I change my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FreeClimb/a13Ldf58/23/) and now this works fine!